# Cannot convert relative path ~/.gradle/daemon/6.4.1 to an absolute file

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to configure libgdx on Inteliij IDE using gradle and im getting error:

```
Cannot convert relative path ~/.gradle/daemon/6.4.1 to an absolute file.
```

I have no idea how to solve it and didn't find any solution on the internet. Can you help me?

Comment: That is not a relative path. What platform are you using? Change `~` to your home folder.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 31. I have gradle installed in ~/.gradle. It's also in my project directory (.gradle as well as gradle), but both produce the same error (Cannot convert relative path ./.gradle/daemon/6.4.1 to an absolute file.)

Comment: Also I have no idea what's "absolute file". It's like absolute path?

Comment: `./.gradle` **is** a relative path. Change that first `.` to your **home folder**. It's like absolute power, it corrupts absolutely. Sorry, I have no idea either. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But I don't really understand what happended - isn't ~ my home folder?

Comment: The symbol `~` is converted to your home folder by the shell. Java is not a shell. `System.getProperty("user.home")` will work to give you the home folder (in Java). Groovy and Gradle are both Java hosted languages.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to File ⇒ Settings ⇒ Build, Execution, Deployment ⇒ Build Tools ⇒ Gradle, and change `gradle user home` to `/home/your-linux-account/.gradle` instead of `~/.gradle`.

It seems like IntelliJ just doesn't translate the tilde `~` to the home directory of the user, so it has to be written out.